# C# sorted list - fast, with removable, duplicated Keys

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I making a application with compression mechanism and need my own Dictionary. Every cicle in my app, It adds new element into a myDictionary and update(add a char to some previous elements in myDictionary ). I was doing it with normal list and Quicksort function, but it was really slow. I'm searching for some new methods how to do this but SortedList, Dictionary or LookUp doesnt seems like what I looking for. Is it better to make my own SortedList or is too hard/complex to manage?

Some of the code:

```
public class MyDictionary
{
    private List<string> Contexts;
    private List<string> Contents;
    private int Count;  //words count

    //Konstruktor
    public MyDictionary()
    {
        Count = 0;
        Contexts = new List<string>();
        Contents = new List<string>();
    }
```

## region Public Functions

```
    public void AddChar(char ch, int contentSize)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            if (Contents[i].Length < contentSize)
            {
                Contents[i] = Contents[i] + ch;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(string context, string content)
    {
        Contexts.Add(Reverse(context)); //otočený kontext
        Contents.Add(content);
        Count++;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        quicksort(Contexts, Contents, 0, Count-1);
    }

    private void quicksort(List<String> context, List<String> content, int left, int right)
    {
        int i = left, j = right;
        string pivot = context[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (context[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
            {
                i++;
            }

            while (context[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
            {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j)
            {
                swap(i,j);                                  
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        // Recursive calls
        if (left < j)
        {
            quicksort(context, content, left, j);
        }

        if (i < right)
        {
            quicksort(context, content, i, right);
        }
    }

    private static string Reverse(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code and what exception you're getting?

Comment: Please share some code with us. It's unclear what you trying to do

Comment: post updated with code... I just want to know, if is there better solution(probably is- im beginner) The application calling Add() AddChar() and update() every cicle...

Comment: Did you try a   SortedDictionary()?

Comment: I need something similar to a SortedList or SortedDictionary except that it should allow duplicate keys.

Comment: If it allows duplicate keys, it isn't a dictionary anymore.

Comment: You could use a `SortedDictionary<TKey, List<TValues>>`

Comment: @OFOuch Yes, but you probably want to reverse those generic arguments (see my previous comment).

Comment: I need duplicated keys, Can i have like this and with my own comparer(DuplicateKeyComparer): 
SortedDictionary<List<string>, string> dictionaryData = new SortedDictionary<List<string>, string>(new DuplicateKeyComparer<List<string>>());
Maybe I replace SortedDictionary with SortedList

Comment: But that comparer probably not work. :/... I need quick sorting in list with duplicated keys. And that sort happens just when I add a new element

Comment: If I would make a linkedList and make sort just for the element which I am just adding. Is it efficient or is better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class that acts like a `SortedDictionary`, but can hold multiple values with the same key.  You may need to flesh it out a little bit, with methods like `Remove`, and adding support for your own `IComparer<TKey>` if you need them. [LINQPad file](http://share.linqpad.net/4rps75.linq)

```
public class SortedMultiValue<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<TValue>
{
    private SortedDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> _data;

    public SortedMultiValue()
    {
        _data = new SortedDictionary<TKey, System.Collections.Generic.List<TValue>>();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _data.Clear();
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (!_data.TryGetValue(key, out List<TValue> items))
        {
            items = new List<TValue>();
            _data.Add(key, items);
        }
        items.Add(value);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> Get(TKey key)
    {
        if (_data.TryGetValue(key, out List<TValue> items))
        {
            return items;
        }
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return CreateEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return CreateEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerable<TValue> CreateEnumerable()
    {
        foreach (IEnumerable<TValue> values in _data.Values)
        {
            foreach (TValue value in values)
            {
                yield return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var data = new SortedMultiValue<string, string>();

data.Add("Dog", "Buddy");
data.Add("Dog", "Mr. Peanutbutter");
data.Add("cat", "Charlie");
data.Add("cat", "Sam");
data.Add("cat", "Leo");

foreach (string item in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.WriteLine();
foreach (string item in data.Get("cat"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.WriteLine();
foreach (string item in data.Get("Dog"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

It produces this as the output (notice that the first group of names is sorted by the key they were inserted with):

> Charlie
> Sam
> Leo
> Buddy
> Mr. Peanutbutter
>
> Charlie
> Sam
> Leo
>
> Buddy
> Mr. Peanutbutter

Comment: Ah. I did not know what you meant before, but now I get it. It looks good. I will try It, until that thank you for your help :)

Comment: I was getting some errors in methods Get and Add on items. Is this edit alright? 
`List<TValue> items;
            if (_data.TryGetValue(key, out items))  `

Comment: This code is using C# 7 features, if you are not using C# 7, change those `if` statements to `List<TValue> items;
  if (!_data.TryGetValue(key, out  items))`

Comment: I got into a problem, because in my main app, I need index of the elements from this dictionary. If I use SortedList it doesnt help because only keys are indexed and there is multiple values in list. I probably need to think about this problem longer and have different aproach. But if you have some idea about this problem, im free :-D. Still thank you for help

Comment: I can add that fairly easily. Give me an hour or so to get home

Comment: How would you like getting the index of an item to work?  I could to `int SortedMultiValue.GetIndex(TValue value)` or calling `Get()` could return a list of classes with the values and their indexes for that key.  How "dynamic" does the index need to be (will you add additional items after requesting an index, or can index generation wait until after all the items are adding)?  What do you want to get back if there are multiple items  with the same value stored under (the same or) different keys?

Comment: In my main program every cicle I add some elements into my dictionary and after that I get index of the matching key element which is similar to my string and index of the matchmaking value element  which is similar to my string. I trying to have fast performance in this. If is it possible.